Recover postgres database from data directory, forgotten password
I have a following problem.
I had a database with data in docker.
I create a backup of a data directory, and cleaned docker volumes.
However, I do not have the password to the old database.
Can the password be reset somehow ?
Thanks :)
I tried editing pg_hba.conf file, and running postgres docker container with edited file, did not help.
Is it possible to import data directory to existing database ?
Update:
I edited pg_hba.conf file:
pg_hba file
I run postgres from the data directory (correct version).
In another terminal I  run
psql -h /tmp -U postgres
But the answer is FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist.

There is no password to the old database, just to users in a running instance. It is difficult to say more because "did not help" provides no information, you haven't said how you created your backup nor how you tried to restore it.

I just copied the local docker volume directory to another place.

I tried to just map the folder to a new docker container with new environment variables POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, e.t.c.
However, when I try to login with these credentials it says role user does not exist

OK, so read up on changing pg_hba.conf in docker to allow trust authentication. Then you can set a new password and restore normal authentication

Tried it, but it does not work. I do not know what I am doing wrong.
Details are in the edit above.
